# Como obter o número da linha em PHP?

Tags: php, método

Como posso estar obtendo o número da linha em que o método foi executado por exemplo?

#### class.php

```
Class Example
{
    function methodExample()
    {
        echo __LINE__;
    }
}
```

#### index.php

```
include "class.php";

Example::methodExample(); // 5
```

A utilização do `_LINE_` não faz o que eu desejo, já que o mesmo exibe a linha onde foi inserido e não onde o método foi chamado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passe o número da linha atual como argumento para o método (ele tem que ter um parâmetro para receber este argumento). Ou use o [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) para obter toda informação de chamada (mais lento).

```
Class Example {
    function methodExample($line) {
        echo $line . "\n";
    }
    function methodExample2() {
        echo debug_backtrace()[0]["line"];
    }
}
Example::methodExample(__LINE__);
Example::methodExample2();
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/GWGhAv). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ogozescc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Engine/ProgramLine.php).